# Clickhouse-client Code: 36. DB::Exception: Positional options are not supported. (BAD_ARGUMENTS) bash script

Tags: bash, clickhouse, xargs

Here is my bash script for inserting parquets in parallel to clickhouse. It keeps giving me the error I put in the title though and I don't know why. Any help is appreciated

```
#!/bin/bash
time (for FILENAME in /mnt/sdc/traces/part-*.snappy.parquet; do
            echo $FILENAME
            xargs -P 6 -n 1 -0 clickhouse-client --receive_timeout=100000 --query=\"INSERT INTO ethereum.traces FORMAT Parquet\" < $FILENAME
        done)
```

Comment: Just to be clear: `.parquet` files are in a format such that if xargs word-splits them, each word is a separate argument to `clickhouse-client`? Because only if that's true does this answer make any sense.

Comment: And btw, the answer telling you to remove the backslashes is _definitely_ correct. I'm not sure it's an answer, because I'm not convinced that it's the only problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to implement this would look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
cpu_count=6
batch_size=4

printf '%s\0' /mnt/sdc/traces/part-*.snappy.parquet |
  xargs -P"$cpu_count" -n"$batch_size" -0 sh -c '
    for filename in "$@"; do
      echo "$filename"
      clickhouse-client --receive_timeout=100000 --query="INSERT INTO ethereum.traces FORMAT Parquet" <"$filename"
    done
  ' _
```

- `xargs` requires its stdin to be a list of arguments to pass to the program it invokes. That wasn't the case at all in your original code, which was passing xargs parquet files directly on its stdin -- whereas here, we're passing it *a NUL-delimited list of names of parquet files*.
- The `-n` argument to `xargs` tells it how many files to pass to each copy of `sh`. Using a low number like 1 reduces the chance that you won't be parallelizing well when the number of files left is below the batch size, but increases the performance overhead of starting up new shells.

Comment: Thanks that works and I appreciate the feedback because I'm new to using xargs

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the backslash in front of those two double-quotes.

Comment: Still gives the same error

Comment: This works for me (on my Mac):

`#!/bin/bash
time (for FILENAME in ./*.parquet; do
            echo $FILENAME
            ./clickhouse client --receive_timeout=100000 --query="INSERT INTO ethereum.traces FORMAT Parquet" < $FILENAME
        done)`

Comment: If I leave the slashes in before the quotes, I get your error above

Comment: This version ```#!/bin/bash
time (for FILENAME in /mnt/sdc/traces/part-*.snappy.parquet; do
            echo $FILENAME
            clickhouse-client --receive_timeout=100000 --query="INSERT INTO ethereum.traces FORMAT Parquet" < $FILENAME
        done)``` works but I wanted to use xargs so it could run in parallel.

Comment: I see. Maybe this is a bash script and xargs question? (I only know how write a bash script by searching StackOverflow.)  :)

Comment: @RichRaposa, this should be a comment, not an answer, unless you're prepared to defend it as addressing the OP's issue _in full_.

Comment: Just trying to help...and dropping the quotes worked for me. And StackOverflow is tricky - you can't post comments unless you have enough points, which are hard to get when you can't comment. So it's a bit of a catch-22. I only recently acquired the "honorary privilege" of commenting.